# Is writing the pronoun "i" in lowercase a feature of Indian English?

Tags: orthography, pronouns, capitalization, formality, subcontinental-english

### The Rule

The personal pronoun “I” is always capitalized in English,  regardless of its position in a sentence. This is an orthographic convention that every native speaker should know.

Whenever I have seen anyone breaking this ‘rule’ online, irrespective of their nationality, I've tended to make the following assumptions:

1. a typo
2. fatigue (pressing that shift key can be so exhausting)
3. ignorance

For *ignorance* I don't mean stupidity, I mean that the writer (of any nationality) either chooses to ‘ignore’ the rule, or he is ignorant of its existence. This can be caused by a person's first language (or mother tongue) interference. For example, the italian personal pronoun, *io*,  is only capitalized at the beginning of a sentence, and coincidentally, the lowercase letter is also adopted for the words *italiana* and *italiano*.

So it was quite an eye-opener to read the following, posted on EL&U nearly three years ago.

> But **i read a fantastic article** some years back that convinced me to write a small "i" instead of a capital one, and to make the y capital in "You" to show more respect to the person, and **attach a modesty to oneself**.
>   <sub>[jeega](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80749/44619) (Sep 5 '12)</sub>

I'm not 100% certain, but I believe jeega is Indian, and it's indisputable that many Indian speakers who are learning English have a tendency to write the subject pronoun “I” in lowercase.

### Questions

1. How established is this praxis among Indian English speakers?
2. Is writing **i** a means of circumventing the perceived limitations of the English language?
3. Can anyone confirm this practice, and/or provide a link to the aforementioned article?
4. Because English is continuously evolving and it has become, for better or for worse, the 21st century lingua franca, I wouldn't be surprised if **I** was written **i** in two generation times. Are there any studies on this eventuality?

---

Related:

- [Why is the pronoun “I” written with an uppercase letter, even when it's not at the beginning of a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111616/why-is-the-pronoun-i-written-with-an-uppercase-letter-even-when-its-not-at-t?lq=1)
- [Why should the first person pronoun 'I' always be capitalized?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized)
- [Is it alright to use lowercase “i” or should you always use “I” (uppercase)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172/is-it-alright-to-use-lowercase-i-or-should-you-always-use-i-uppercase?lq=1)

Comment: I've seen "i" in discussion forums (or would it be "fora"?) a few times and I assumed it was due to ignorance or carelessness.  This is a good question and I'd like to hear what you guys have to say.

Comment: I don't think it's particularly a feature of *Indian* English. Many people now do so much more of their casual communication in *writing* (on the Internet, text messaging, etc.) where capitalizing actually requires *more effort* (as well as basic knowledge of "correct" usage, which obviously many "IE" speakers don't necessarily have). But I really can't see the lower-case "i" taking over in my lifetime, any more than we're likely to convert ***to be*** into a regular verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I don't mean the lowercase i is peculiar to Indian English, as I already listed this can be due to a typo, a "fatigue" i.e. laziness, or ignorance. Italian learners commit this orthographic mistake very often, especially in the beginning. You're asking someone who has written *io* since they could hold a pen in their hand, to change a habit of a lifetime!

Comment: So, to distinguish this from your linked 'related' questions, are you only asking here if lowercase 'i' for first-person singular nominal is especially common in Indian English online writing than other varieties? You have four questions at the end; frankly the first one is answerable by a statistical study of corpora (easy to state but difficult to actually implement) (and to do otherwise is a bit singling out an ethnicity based on a vague notion of someone's name).

Comment: @Mitch I'm asking whether it's true that Indian English speakers choose to write it in lowercase for the reason that jeega stated.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: I certainly wouldn't ask you to start capitalising **io** in your native Italian! But bear in mind that English has a certain amount of "status" value to many IE speakers, so *on average* it would be somewhat self-defeating for them to *deliberately* flaunt a non-standard usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers perhaps I didn't make myself clear, if in your native language you were used to express the first person singular pronoun in small letters, it obviously requires  a certain amount of self discipline to change that habit when learning to write English. In speech we don't hear if words have capital letters or not, because it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: change "whether it's true that Indian English" to "if it is common for English". I am uncomfortable with exclusively singling out Indians, and the broad statement is too much stated as a rule.

Comment: @Mitch there is a link attached to jeega, read the rest of his post, it seems plausible to me that he is Indian. But I have no proof. And your suggestion re corpora can and will prove nothing. And you know it. We have to look *online*, on Facebook, on Youtube, on EL&U. That's where you'll find evidence of this change, or if there is one. EDIT: Are you accusing me of being racist? I mentioned Italians making this orthographic mistake. We all know British and American speakers commit this spelling error, do I *really* have to mention every single nationality for political correctness?

Comment: What are "the perceived limitations of the English language"? How is English being limited or constrained here? Are you saying that choosing one capitalization style is limiting? Most European languages do not capitalize nationality 'Ils sont francais' but 'They are French'.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: My key point was that I think even within the last *decade*, the proportion of all written English communications which are made by non-native, uneducated, or careless writers has increased dramatically (because of certain technological changes). Consequently we can expect to see a much higher proportion of "mistakes", but I don't see the definition of "correct usage" changing any time soon. Especially not because of influence from ***IE***, specifically because of the "status" aspect.

Comment: @Mitch [Why doesn't the English language have distinct words to use when talking to elders?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241074/why-doesnt-the-english-language-have-distinct-words-to-use-when-talking-to-elde)

Comment: To more directly respond to what I think your perception is, I'm sure that there is some very small set of people who, like e e cummings, avoid capitalization for ideological reasons, most people who use lowercase 'i' and textspeak simplifications like 'ur' or 'cuz' do so simply out of efficiency (if you must, call it lazy; it is annoying youthful style and is not tolerated in school work or professional work, but that ain't texting).

Comment: The real problem is simply what @FumbleFingers has stated: “written English communications [...] made by **non-native, uneducated, or careless** writers”.

Comment: @FumbleFingers IE will have a huge influence on English as “she is spoke”. Wait and see, look at how AmEng has revolutionised the language. It's inevitable, I'm sorry. What is the population of India, 700 million citizens? And you don't think they won't have any influence? The English language is a mish mash, it's never been "pure" in the first place. The people who speak and write English will force it to change, and that includes textspeak—which I personally hate, but it's here to stay.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: It's never been pure, but it *is* compartmentalized to some extent.

Comment: @tchrist **typo** = carelessness; **ignorance** = uneducated; **fatigue** = laziness/textspeak; and  **first language interference** = non-native..

Comment: @Mari-Lou: As it happens, the *majority* of my dozen closest neighbours are either Indian-born or second-generation immigrants from India/Pakistan. I know they're not *necessarily* representative of hundreds of millions of "indigenous" Indians, but I think you ignore/underestimate the importance of "status" (in what is after all an incredibly class-conscious nation, where the caste system still dominates). I seriously doubt the upwardly-mobile section of society would want to shoot themselves in the foot by publicizing current incompetence whilst attempting to "innovate" for the future.

Comment: It's not going to happen overnight, besides the lowercase *i* is already a reality. Perpetuated by young native speakers as well as non. Read the second sentence in my question: *This is an orthographic convention that every native speaker* ***should*** *know.*

Comment: (Written about half an hour go, but I had an African power cut. You've all moved on since, but I'll post anyway)  Perhaps of interest to Mari-Lou: Norwegian has a T-V distinction in which the intimate _du_ is lower-case while the formal _De_ is upper-case, as is its accusative (_Dem_) and possessive (_Deres_). In fact the lower-case _deres_ means something else entirely, namely "theirs". Norwegians trying to write formal English usually want to capitalise accordingly and refer to Your letter of the 3rd in which You place an order for, and so on.

Comment: @DavidPugh What's an African power cut? :) But thanks for chipping in, Italian too has the same distinction, we capitalize *Lei* and *Loro* (he/she and they) especially in  formal correspondence. But I'm hearing it used, less and less.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: The power company cuts the power to my _quartier_ usually once a day, and not at the same time every day. I'm on a laptop, but the modem is on the mains. So no participation when the power is off. Yes, I, too, fear for a future in which people won't be able to read the canon because it's not in textspeak, the way I can't read _Beowulf_. Me, I write SMS in full-bore English (and French with accents, if my cellphone supports them), out of sheer cussedness.

Comment: Just thought it should be mentioned that poet [e e cummings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E._E._Cummings) adopted the style of forgoing all upper case characters (save for references to God).  Thus he referred to himself as "i".

Comment: @HotLicks Mitch already mentioned e e cummings, thanks anyway. But I'm specifically speaking about the personal pronoun, written as either I or i. I've actually tried looking for that article, it's a shame not being able to refer to it, I quite liked the idea that someone felt they could portray their "modesty" and meekness  by means of a simple lowercase. Oh well...

Comment: Just another  related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105180/can-u-and-i-part-ways-with-stack-exchange

Comment: This is not restricted to India. It is (unfortunately) also, for whatever reason, very common in central Europe: southern Germany, Belgium, northern part of Switzerland, Austria, Czech Republic, and Poland. And they are all very stubborn about it. They even use it in business emails.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I've just checked, the current population in India is 1.252 billion, and [India now claims to be the world's **second-largest English-speaking country**. The most reliable estimate is around 10% of its population or 125 million people, second only to the US and **expected to quadruple in the next decade**.](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-20500312). We will be seeing more Indian English expressions, modified idioms and phrasal verbs, and other cultural changes in the English language. Interesting times ahead for linguists etc.

Comment: I am Australian. When I'm writing quick emails or chatting online I often write "I" as a lower case "i" and don't capitalise the beginnings of sentences. Many other people do they same thing. For example, I can tell when I am Skype messaging with someone on a phone, as opposed to a computer, as their sentences will be auto-corrected to have a capital at the beginning when they are using the phone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Those aren’t native speakers.

Comment: @tchrist You're referring to Indian English speakers. No, they aren't, but many are competent speakers. You're point being? That English will not be affected by this influx, this wave of ESL speakers? I don't understand. EDIT: I'm getting a little weary of all this. I feel I am being attacked, when I am only asking for clarification. I was not disrespectful to anyone.

Comment: @Mari-LouA [The United States has a thousand native English speakers for each native English speaker in India](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_English-speaking_population): a factor of 1000:1 cannot be ignored. If your point is how regions with many ESL speakers augment the original’s lexicon, that is very well-documented (*alligator,avocado, banana,barbecue, cafeteria,canyon, corral,fiesta, hurricane,llama,peon,puma, ranch,salsa,tuna*, &c), but those are **lexical** items not changes to grammar or orthography, especially in the standard written language. It is the same here.

Comment: @tchrist the Internet will change that. The Internet is already changing our perceptions and internal rules of the language. Nothing is set in stone. That includes grammar, punctuation, and spelling. Didn't Webster call English; The *American* language? Did he not write *The American Spelling Book* and *An American Dictionary of the English Language* etc..?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: From your own link, *The most vocal demands for English teaching now come from India's most disadvantaged communities.* Given the nature of Indian culture, I expect those "disadvantaged" communities will continue to be looked down on for at least another couple of generations by "better-educated" sectors of the population, who will probably continue to ascribe high status to "Standard English". I can't honestly see "Indian pidgin English" playing a prominent role in what's heading to be the global standard lingua franca.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I don't know if you've seen this already, but the article Jeega was talking about appears to be the one linked to from this answer: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/493/77227

Comment: @sumelic No, I haven't! But I have now. An article, and an American one to boot, that **suggests** writing the personal pronoun, I, as **i** is an act of humbleness. Could you please write an answer including an excerpt? It could very well have been the article Jeega was referring to.

Comment: Now-a-days it has become common to attribute everything that seems odd to Indian English. I have never written personal pronoun in lower case. Just some people did that doesn't mean everyone do that and it also doesn't mean it's a kind of Indian English. I don't think the reason Jeega stated is correct. We(Indians) have never thought like that. To show respect we use Sir/Madam and it's not like what Jeega said.

Answer (score 46):

**TL;DR:**

I'd hate for anyone to walk away with the idea that Indians think 'i' is acceptable. You won't find it in any respected Indian publication. You won't find the average Indian writing it down on paper. It's just textspeak and that's why it's common in text and tweets and comments online.

---

**Detailed answer:**

I’m from India. I assure you there’s no such thing as the lowercase 'i'. No grammar teacher of mine — and I've had quite a few good ones — ever so much as mentioned it. In fact, this is the first I'm hearing of it.

The tendency of Indians to write in textspeak is unfortunate, but 'i' is as erroneous as 'u'.

I'd like to point out that almost all of these violations occur in the electronic medium. Nobody writes 'i' on paper. They type it. And if there's no autocorrect, most of them can't be bothered to rectify it themselves.

> How established is this practice among Indian English speakers?

Based on my experience, this is pretty established, but not so much among Indian English speakers as among Indian netizens.

> Is writing **i** a means of circumventing the perceived limitations of the English language?

If you mean the limitations regarding the [tiered system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urdu#Politeness) of politeness, then no. The tiered system affects more pronouns than 'I', and affects verbs and modifiers as well.

I might as well mention that Hindi's script *Devanagari* (or any other Indian script I'm familiar with) does *not* have the concept of capital and small letters. So, the question of whether this practice is a carry-over is moot in this case (unlike that of some European languages).

> Can anyone confirm this practice, and/or provide a link to the aforementioned article?

Don't know about the link, but I can confirm that what you have there is a practice evolved solely for digital media. Admittedly Indians use it a bit more, but it's not exclusive to Indian English and shouldn't be considered a part of it.

I don't know what article Jeega was referring to, but that was just an opinion piece, an opinion he seemed to agree with. But it's definitely NOT a feature of [Indian English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English). I'll eat my words if anyone can provide a shred of evidence to the contrary.

EDIT: Sumelic seems to have unearthed the article link in [his answer below](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/264653/77339).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52688/discussion-on-answer-by-tushar-raj-is-the-lowercase-pronoun-i-a-feature-of-ind).

Comment: I'm sorry, but in light of Ari's recent answer, i have to withdraw my green tick. The Times of India is indeed a very reputable Indian publication, and it used the lowercase pronoun i albeit for a short period.

Comment: It's a pity that the comments have been shifted to chat, they were on topic and provided extra info and clarification.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I personally find TOI to be very pretentious, and I'm not surprised they tried to pull this gimmick. Clearly, it backfired. If anything, the failure of a leading daily to sway the masses should be seen as a vindication of the uppercase `I` in InE. I respect your decision, but one swallow does not a summer make.

Comment: NB Your answer convinced me that the lowercase i is not an accepted feature in IE. However, you did say *You won't find it in any respected Indian publication.* The editor's decision must have been spurred by something, by a need to experiment, and that is either an act of courage, or tomfoolery. Whatever. Jeega's comment, in the end, had some foundation and with Ari's answer, they provide the tiny, minuscule shred of evidence.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I also said I'll eat my words if there's evidence. <Chomp>. But no, Jeega's comment had no foundation. The whole argument about the lowercase `i` being modest comes from that being the case in some European languages. And it's those speakers that might feel the need for this in English. It's those speakers that this article was referring to. Indians never had this problem with uppercase `I`. As I recently edited into my post: Indian languages don't even have capital/small letters. We only have one kind. (Btw, I'm still reeling from the news that TOI actually tried to pull it.)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I agree with Tushar Raj. Just one person decided to use lowercase I or one newspaper decided to use it for a short period of time doesn't mean that many Indians do so. I feel it is a kind of prejudice. The reason Jeega stated is  absolutely non sense. And it's disputable that many Indian speakers who are learning English have a tendency to write the subject pronoun _I_  in lowercase. You may see it written by Indians or anyone else but that's just because of any of the reasons you said in the OP.

Answer (score 20):

Jeega's post has a number of features.   It shows Jeega's awareness of the usual convention.   It hints that Jeega used to follow that convention.   It mentions a reason to defy that convention and follow an alternate.   It alludes to but does not cite a source which would support that reason.

There are also, of course, a number of features that Jeega's answer lacks.   Notably, it lacks any mention of ethnicity, national origin or dialect of preference, and it lacks any attempt to persuade us to adopt this alternate convention.

I see no reason to associate Jeega's individual, unconventional choice with any particular dialect.   It seems far simpler to regard this alternate convention as one person's idiosyncratic choice—an intentional distance placed between one idiolect and whichever dialect may encompass it.   Whichever dialect that may be seems irrelevant, both because that dialect cannot be discerned and because that dialect does, in fact, capitalize the first-person singular subjective pronoun.

The post in question does not and cannot support the idea that Indian English in particular is undergoing any sort of change.   At best, it very weakly supports the idea that some unidentified dialect exists which is *not* undergoing this particular change.

Comment: Fair point, perhaps I jumped the gun thinking Jeega could have been (or was) Indian, I admit to have been influenced by a previous comment of his or hers: *I think it is not weird to use capital Y in 'You' because unlike in French and Hindi where You has the form "vous" and "aap/tum" respectively, to show more respect and politeness*. Nevertheless, I was left feeling very curious about the article, which s/he mentions but fails to provide the title of. Thank you for posting. (From a cursory online search, it seems *jeega* is a woman's name)

Comment: [Jeega's post](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/80749/4972) (an answer that has garnered 9 __downvotes__ (speculate as needed)) mention of Hindi and its aap/tum distinction is reasonable evidence that the person, if not actually Indian, has much more familiarity with Hindi than the average person not of Indian origin.

Comment: It was at seven downvotes when I quoted this poster. I am sorry that I inadvertently caused such animosity.

Comment: The mention of French happens to precede the mention of Hindi, @Mitch.  I don't think I should count that as evidence supporting Jeega's possible European origin.  I only count is as proof of an awareness of the T-V distinction.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan yes. This is all speculation based on the wink of a gnat's eye.

Answer (score 6):

A leading daily in India did decide to use the lowercase 'i' instead for 'I' for a brief period of time. Though I don't find that to be the case now.

Facts are as under:

**The Daily**

---

[*The Times of India*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times_of_India)

> *The Times of India* (TOI) is an Indian English-language daily newspaper. It is the third-largest newspaper in India by circulation and largest selling English-language daily in the world according to Audit Bureau of Circulations (India). It is the oldest English-language newspaper in India still in circulation, with its first edition published in 1838. In 1991, the BBC ranked *The Times of India* among the world's six best newspapers.
>   <sub>Wikipedia</sub>

**The Style**

---

[*Handbook of Journalism and Media: India, Bharat, Hindustan*
By Kovuuri G. Reddy Vikas Publishing House, 2015](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eapDDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Proper nouns are always capitalised, but this also depends on ones style or trends of the time. For example, 'I' is always capitalised, but 'I' is used in its lower case (i) in *Times of India*.

**Peoples' reaction**

---

Blog

<sub>Posted 03/04/12 - 8:04 PM:</sub>
Subject: **[i versus I](http://www.thecouchforum.com/comments.php?id=1932)** : *Times Of India*

> I have subscribed to Times of India last week, after a gap of about 4 years. Something I noticed in the editorial columns is a prevalence or clear dominance of 'i' for first person singular pronoun, over 'I'. This was not the case with TOI editorial columns four years ago, when I used to peruse it regularly.
>
> Now what has happened?
>
> There seem to be two possibilities:
>
> 1. Either all of the TOI writers have switched to 'i' because it has gained some popularity in journalism.
> 2. Or editor(s) of TOI prefer 'i' for some unknown reasons.
>
> I don't know exactly what the reason is...

**Motivation?**

---

From TOI editorial

### [**my little i**](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/jug-suraiya/jugular-vein/my-little-i/articleshow/1746637.cms)

<sub>Jug Suraiya | TNN | Mar 10, 2007, 11.45 PM IST</sub>

> you've noticed that i've been cut down to size, and good thing too. being the perspicacious reader that you are, not once did you think that the stoi was losing it **when it began to write the first person singular, the capital, upper case i** (which we can't show here anymore, but you know what it looks like, a sort of high-rise or i-rise i) ***as a small, lower case i.***
>
> no, far from thinking that stoi was now chucking out typographical protocol, having long chucked out various norms of grammar, syntax, rhetoric, prosody, orthography and other pettifogging rules of verbal engagement, you at once surmised the philosophical underpinnings of the metamorphosis of the great big self-promoting capital i for i-dolatory into a self-effacing small i, an i that knows its place and doesn't try to get above itself. which of course was exactly what it was doing. in our i-centric (rather than you-centric, or even he-centric) language, it was i which assumed capital, upper case proportions. you and he enjoyed no such exalted status. this type-casting amplification of i in print had a correspondingly inflationary effect on the inner i of the ego (should it really be spelt i-go?).
>
> nowhere was this enlargement of the ego like a pneumatic tyre swelling under air pressure more evident than in the effusions of sunday columnists, such as myself. particularly myself. does this fellow have an i-dentity problem, or what?, readers would ask.
>
> ok, so he sometimes makes passing reference to bunny and brindle, but mainly he writes about himself, first person singular. it's all i i i i i, like a stuck ipod. the only excuse i have is that columnists are supposed to write on subjects they know something about. and as the only subject i can claim the remotest acquaintance with is that admittedly very limited, and limiting, branch of knowledge that is myself, i had little option but to resort to i-teration. and you can see the consequences. the stoi has whittled me, and the other columnists (poor things, though no fault of theirs), down to lower case size.
>
> but why not decapitalise the works? not just i, but everything: proper nouns, acronyms, initial letters after full stops, and other punctuation marks which end sentences. the whole jing-bang lot. i mean, fair's fair. if i'm going to be i, why shouldn't george w bush be george w bush, or the usa be the usa, or god be god, or indeed, the big b be the small b? or for that matter, why shouldn't that last o after that question mark be a lower case, uncapitalised o. what's this o got that i haven't, puffing itself up like that just because it starts a sentence? big deal. or rather, small deal.
>
> and as you know, there's a literary tradition of decapitalisation going all the way back to american poet don marquis who in 1927 had a cockroach called archy who would sneak into the typewriter at night and type out the ongoing saga of mehitabel the alley cat who claimed to be an avatar of queen cleopatra who in reincarnated life had fallen on hard times. not to mention lower case times, because her chronicler, archy, being a cockroach, couldn't press the typewriter key for capitals so everything came out in small letters: i have had my ups and downs/ but wotthehell wotthehell/ yesterday sceptres and crowns/ fried oysters and velvet gowns/ and today i herd with bums.
>
> mehitabel wasn't the only one to be downsized. another american poet, e e cummings (1894-1962), also eschewed not only capitals but also punctuation marks: it's/ spring/when the world is puddle-wonderful/ the queer/ old balloonman whistles/ far and wee. true yogis, mehitabel and old e e, who mastered their upper case egos. and what more appropriate way to better their yogic instruction than for me to upend myself, sirshasan-wise, and turn myself into an ulta-pulta?

**Sample Story**

---

### **[A tale of two cities](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/edit-page/A-tale-of-two-cities/articleshow/12706327.cms?)**

<sub>Boria Majumdar | Apr 18, 2012, 12.00 AM IST</sub>

> With 100 days to go before the 2010 Commonwealth Games, everything was falling apart in the Indian capital. The Games Village was half done, and one corruption scandal after the other was rocking the games preparations. Even the world leaders had expressed concern over India's ability and preparedness to host the Games. Forced to intervene in the chao-tic situation, the prime minister constituted a core committee to do damage control.
>
> Now with 100 days to go before the Olympic Games begin in London on July 27, the city is already geared up to becoming the cynosure of the world's gaze. Having seen the games preparations over the last few days, it's evident that London is almost ready to host the spectacular sporting event.
>
> On the eve of the Commonwealth Games, when  **i** spoke to Delhiites, the common refrain was that an unnecessary white elephant had been thrust on them. There was little community integration and an even lesser sense of pride at Delhi hosting the games. London, on the other hand, presents a different picture. While there are concerns over excessive spending on the games and its impact on the British economy, the local Londoner is excited at being a resident of an Olympics host city....

---

### Now The Question:

'*and it's indisputable that many Indian speakers who are learning English have a tendency to write the subject pronoun “I” in lowercase.*'

Would the OP like to share the data upon which this observation of hers, is based?

What I am trying to gather is whether a simple rule of 'writing' is picked up differently by native and non native 'speakers'.

In any case, which portion of Indian demography is being referred to here? Kids in school, freshmen or adults? A quantified parameter for the comparison; something like percent lower case 'i' per capita, would be interesting to know.

Comment: Wow! But the answer needs to be formatted, use blockquotes, and the excerpts could perhaps do with shortening a bit.

Comment: One can read the poet cummings [sic] here https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poetrymagazine/poems/detail/49493

Comment: The  use of **i**  is just something that I *used to* notice quite a bit, here on ELU, but also on different forums.  the trend seems less marked nowadays. So I'm sorry, I don't have any official data that I can share with you.

Comment: I dont't question your observations or inferences,  only thing which bothers me  is that being a native speaker may have little to do with it @Mari-LouA

Comment: I'm happy that Mr. Suraiya spared the content and just decided to do his thing in the editorials. I'm even happier that he stopped. Something to be noted.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any particular connection to Indian English. The idea that lower-case "i" is somehow more humble did appear in a New York Times essay by Caroline Winter about the English first-person singular pronoun, "[Me, Myself and I](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/08/03/magazine/03wwln-guestsafire-t.html)" (hat tip to [Neil Fein](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/161/neil-fein) for locating the article in [his answer to the question "Is it alright to use lowercase 'i' or should you always use 'I'"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/172/is-it-alright-to-use-lowercase-i-or-should-you-always-use-i-uppercase/493#493).) It seems likely to me that this is the article Jeega was referring to.

The essay covers several aspects of the capital "I", including its history. Most bizarrely from a linguistic standpoint, Winter suggests at several points that the usual capitalization is somehow egoistic or prideful. She refers to "I" as

> the towering single letter that signifies us as discrete beings and
>   connote confidence, dominance and the ambition to pull ourselves up by
>   our own bootstraps.

After a bit of discussion of [I-counting](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2113) in political speech, she hypothesizes that

> perhaps our individualistic, workaholic society would be more rooted
>   in community and quality and less focused on money and success if we
>   each thought of ourselves as a small “i” with a sweet little dot.

The essay concludes with a call to the reader:

> i [sic] suggest that You try, as an experiment, to capitalize those whom You
>   address while leaving yourselves in the lowercase. It may be a
>   humbling experience. It was for me.

Comment: I’m not sure it’s so bizarre from a linguistic point of view. It is a well-established notion in several languages that capitalising a pronoun is a way of showing respect: polite pronouns are capitalised, normal ones are not. Whether the capitalisation originated in respectfulness or not, it is linguistic reality that that’s what users associate it with. No such notion is deliberately cultivated in English, since there is no parallel connection between capitalisation and respect—but that doesn’t mean that similar connotations don’t exist in users of English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It's bizarre because the capitalization is completely conventional. Pretty much nobody thinks about it, just like nobody thinks about the fact that we use the same second-person pronoun for singular and plural.

Comment: That’s false logic, though. The fact that it’s conventional doesn’t necessarily mean that it does not have any effect. I saw a reference to a study in an article once that indicated that German people in general tend to perceive nouns as being more forceful than verbs in German, but that the tendency diminished severely if the nouns they were presented with were not properly capitalised. Capitalising nouns is pure convention in German, but it does seem to have a subconscious effect nonetheless; I’m not aware of any studies on whether the same is true for ‘I’ in English, but it could be.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: When did I make a logical argument? I never said that Winter must be wrong; only that her speculation is bizarre. All kinds of things are conceivable, but my default assumption is that society is not molded by the arbitrary features of particular words. The arbitrariness of the relationship between the signifier and the signified is a fundamental principle of linguistics; exceptions should be justified.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: We could imagine that maybe the diphthong "ai" causes English speakers to perceive the first-person pronoun as having a sense of "playfulness, delicacy and happiness" according to the principle of sound symbolism ("[Synesthesia](https://books.google.com/books?id=rYQ-18Q1ckQC&pg=PA434&lpg=PA434&dq=sound+symbolism+associated+with+diphthong+ai&source=bl&ots=HWGNZs_zJ8&sig=95sVWM-3ZLumXUTwUgrRchLudbU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTiaSq_OfRAhUCwFQKHR7PCyEQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q=sound%20symbolism%20associated%20with%20diphthong%20ai&f=false)", L.E. Marks).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: ...but by itself, this argument would also be ridiculous as a basis for suggesting changing the pronoun in more somber circumstances to something like /a:/ or /au/.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any specific link with Indian English ("indian english"?) but I do have an addendum to your list:

(4) - Stylistic reasons.  One might disagree with it, but the lowercase "i" is *often* a deliberate stylistic choice, a flouting of convention for effect. It's particularly closely associated with poet e.e. cummings, who also rejected the standard English convention of capitalizing proper nouns.

Although the lowercase personal pronoun is strongly associated with textspeak, where it is easier to type, its stylistic use among teenagers is older than that --I remember it being common in the longhand writing of teenage girls in my high school days (circa early 90's), long before texting or online chats.

As is the case with the quote from the OP, the lowercase personal pronoun is typically associated with an almost obtrusive modesty or humbleness --a deliberate lowering of personal status *vis-a-vis* the audience.  Capitalization does have connotations of importance and respect --it's worth noting that English speakers [used to capitalize](http://www.archives.gov/exhibits/charters/constitution_transcript.html) any number of terms that we don't any more (chiefly abstract nouns).

Comment: Wasn't the teenage-girl longhand lower-case I because you otherwise can't make the dot into a heart?

Comment: @DavidPugh Ah, but which came first, the chicken or the egg?

Comment: and archy, (courtesy of Don Marquis), who could be excused proper capitalisation on the grounds that using the shift key is extremely difficult for a cockroach...

Comment: I'm glad you posted this, as it was a distinct lack in the other options presented.  There are occasionally times when I affect extra an extra-casual attitude by lowercasing my entire statement, going so far as to go back and "correct" anything that was auto-corrected to uppercase.  It's situational, and doesn't happen often, but I see value in having it in my repertoire.  Expressing ourselves in text is hard enough, playing with grammar and style, intentionally, gives another dimension through which to add meaning.

Comment: The words capitalized in the constitution are the nouns; German works that way to this day.  As a German I find that a tremendous help with reading. German sentences with all-lowecase nouns are a pain to read. Conversely, the personal pronoun in German is not capitalized in mid-sentence (except for cases where the pluralis majestatis would apply).

Comment: @Jason i do the same thing, including going back and "correcting" caps to lowercase, as a stylistic choice, in (typically) quick informal contexts. I've disabled auto-capitalization in Word, Scrivener, and on my phone. Obviously this can not be put down to either laziness or ignorance. Bad judgement and lack of last are something else entirely.