# What is the shortcut style of writing used by Indian English speakers called?

Tags: single-word-requests, punctuation, orthography, subcontinental-english

One of the things I do is [teaching people how to code](https://ionicabizau.net/blog/35-the-joy-of-being-a-mentor) and I love it. However, something I do *not* like, is that often (twice a week or so), people start conversations like this:

> hi sir
>
> how r u sir
>
> sir , can u help me
>
> can u show me how i can do dis
>
> pls saaaar , help me 4 free

I found that most of these guys are Indians (or at least, from this geographical area). I do love Indians (and all people in general), but I really do *not* like this type of writing.

The closest thing I found is [Indian English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English):

> Indian English is any of the forms of English characteristic of India.

However, I'm pretty sure that *Indian English* does not include this unpleasant style of writing.

From my experience, the specifics are:

- exaggerated use of `sir` (sometimes `saa...aar`)
- lowercase letters
- lack of punctuation, but not lack of commas
- commas have a space before and after
- chat shortcuts:

  - `you` → `u`
  - `are` → `r`
  - `for` → `4`
  - `this` → `dis`
  - `please` → `pls` or `plzzzz`

---

What I want to find out is:

- What's the term/name to describe this style?
- How and when did it appear? What's the history about this style?
- Why is `sir` so much used?

---

<sub>I do not intend this to be in any way racist or something similar, but I'm just trying to understand *why* and *how*.</sub>

Comment: Related: [Is the lowercase pronoun “i” a feature of Indian English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/241207/is-the-lowercase-pronoun-i-a-feature-of-indian-english/241212#241212)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's commonly referred to as [textspeak](http://textspeak), or textese, among other terms.

> Language regarded as characteristic of text messages, consisting of abbreviations, acronyms, initials, emoticons, etc. <sub>(Oxford)</sub>

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_language):

> SMS language or textese (also known as txt-speak, txtese, chatspeak, txt, txtspk, txtk, txto, texting language, txt lingo, SMSish, txtslang, txt talk) or "texting language" is a term for the abbreviations and slang commonly used with mobile phone text messaging, but sometimes used **with other Internet-based communication such as email and instant messaging**.
>
> Three features of early mobile phone messaging encouraged users to use abbreviations: (a) Text entry was difficult, requiring multiple key presses on a small keypad to generate each letter; (b) Messages were limited to 160 characters; and (c) it made texting faster.
>
> Once it became popular it took on a life of its own and was often used outside of its original context. **At its peak, it was the cause of vigorous debate about its potentially detrimental effect on literacy, but with the advent of alphabetic keyboards on smartphones its use, and the controversies surrounding it, have receded and died off.**

<sub>Emphasis mine</sub>

Most of the things you mentioned can be chalked up to textspeak, inluding the lowercase letters and the absence of proper punctuation. They are just shortcuts Indians use frequently, but this practice certainly isn't exclusive to India, and it's not considered part of Indian English as far as I know. (I'm from India.)

In my experience, some Indian netizens simply don't realize that textspeak isn't proper in formal contexts. (This also applies to select contractions, like `wanna`.)

---

The overuse of `sir` is another matter. This is because of the tendency of Indians to convey respect, as they would in their first languages. It's a cultural thing. Indians usually address their superiors and teachers with some sign of verbal respect, and `sir` fills this void in English.

The various spellings you see is how they transliterate their pronunciation (which varies greatly from state to state in India). I'm afraid I'm not sure why they do that. If I could hazard a guess, it originated as a half-joke in informal circles.

Comment: Thanks! What about commas? Why is textspeak so much used by Indians? I talk to people from many countries.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: It bugs me too. Apparently, Indians never got the memo that it's improper in formal settings. They think it's "cool".

Comment: About the commas: count your blessings you've come across users who at least put a space after it. I've often encountered people who put a space before _and not after_. (It's ugly ,trust me.)

Comment: Although this constant “sirring” comes off as the verbal marker of obsequious sycophancy by kowtowing toadies like so many mendicant paupers clutching at one’s hemline, they do this without understanding what a terrible cultural faux pas they’ve committed, because it is normal in their culture but not in ours. These intentions to be polite come off as exactly the opposite.

Comment: @tchrist: Right you are, sir. The thing is, in some Indian formal settings, not 'sirring' would be a faux pas. Worse, the 'sir' might take it personally and deem you unworthy of whatever it is you wanted from him. Generations of such swellheads have preyed upon the people, and now this sycophancy is hardcoded into us. Better safe than sorry, that's what we think.

Comment: Are we sure that the only recipients of these messages are not users of Indian English, or that most of them are not? Not really clear from the question. It's all about what is expected by the people you are communicating well. What is jarring to one interlocutor might well be acceptable, expected, or even required by another interlocutor.